# Execute command in terminal mode at terminal startup

Tags: terminal-buffer

I'm trying to execute simple commands in the vim terminal mode, but cannot get it to work. For example, I tried

```
nmap <F12> :let $VIM_DIR=expand('%:p:h')<CR>:terminal<CR>cd $VIM_DIR<CR>
```

to open a terminal in the directory of the current file, but the final `<CR>` is ignored. I also tried `term_sendkeys("","\<CR>")` but that didn't have any noticeable effect at all.

Comment: For me this works, but only if I map it to a function key below F10, very strange...

Comment: @Bart for me it never works

Comment: Is it Vim or Neovim?

Comment: @Matt this is Vim

Answer (score 1):

I tested that this works.  It assumes that the terminal is opened in buffer 2.
You can check which buffer the terminal is open in with `:ls`.

```
:terminal
CTRL-W W 
:let  $VIM_DIR=expand('%:p:h')
:call term_sendkeys(2, "cd $VIM_DIR\n")
:call term_sendkeys(2, "pwd\n")
```

Also your initial command worked for me.

```
nmap <F12> :let $VIM_DIR=expand('%:p:h')<CR>:terminal<CR>cd $VIM_DIR<CR>
```

It maybe that you are testing this mapping using keys that are already mapped. You can review the nmap mappings with:

```
:nmap
```

Or a specific mapping with:

```
:verb map <F12>
```

`verb` (`verbose`) tells you where the mapping was defined (file and line).